# Skewing a Gaussian (Normal Distribution) …

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution, binomial-distribution

I am trying to model election data.

Say you have a state that is 50-50 Dem-Rep and the state has 100 districts.

Even though the state is 50-50, turnout will vary by district, and plotting the histogram of the vote-share of these districts, they should naturally form a Gaussian centered at 50%. **Let’s assume a standard deviation of 20.**

Now assume voter behavior changes and the state is 70% Democrat. With such a large standard deviation, the resultant histogram will be skewed.

> How do I quantify or show the skewness? What function or process can I use to plot this?

Using excel, one can use the `binom.inv` function, but the standard deviation is 5 for the built-in 50-50 example, and shifting the state to 70% Democrat will not skew the distribution much because the standard deviation is so small. **I also don’t want discrete values.**

I’m thinking of a bag of marbles with 70% blue and 30% red, but this does not allow for changes in standard deviation. As you can see, I’m not sure how to set up this problem.

Comment: What is your goal? Are you trying fit a parametric distribution(Skewed Gaussian) to the random variable describing the vote ratio in 1 district? What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: I want to start with a 50-50 state with 100 districts where the district vote distribution has a standard deviation of 20. First, I am wondering how to model this, because a bag of marbles, half blue and half red, will not have such a wide standard deviation.  
Second, under whatever assumptions, what would the district vote distribution for a state with 60% blue marbles look like.

Comment: Do you believe that all districts have the same probability to vote democrat which equals to the global probability you observe $50\%$ or $70\%$? Which means that the difference you observe are pure noise totally unpredictable with the information you have. Or do you believe that some districts could have a true probability different from the global probability that you could access. Do you know the size of the districts?

Comment: Thanks Max. Yes, I am assuming all districts have the same global probability. All districts are (by law) the same size (around 600,000), but we are only measuring the number of voters, which can vary by up to ~10%. 

I am beginning to understand the Beta function. If I set Alpha=Beta=2.625, I get a parabola-shaped histogram with a standard deviation of 20. Then, holding alpha+beta=constant, I can adjust the mean, which also changes the standard deviation a bit. 

I'm assuming this is the right way to go?